# Build a Blog Archives block with code in php?

Tags: php

i am a new learner of php, i only able to read and write some data into mysql database and some basic php knowledge. now, there is a blog programme. i had wrote some articles.i want to build a Blog Archives block with code by myself. but i even don't know how to begin? the Blog Archives block style as this:

```
2011 year  may month
2011 year  april month
2011 year  march month
....
```

expect someone can give me some tips.first i should do then.....and last solve the question. thank you.

ps:first i know i should do  a research to the database. now, but i don't know how many fields i should necessary.
i found the article created time as this `1305357473`

Comment: what `blog programme` are you using?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: From your comment I understand you have an stored timestamp in your database. Month is an mysql datetime function (read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)) but that won't be of use now.

You should use php to do the something like the following, remember this is an raw example..and would require some detailed input of your own.

```
while($loopTroughResultHere) {

   $oDateTime = new DateTime($aRow['created']);
   $iYear = $oDateTime->format("Y");
   $sMonth = $oDateTime->format("F");

   // Do some isset checking here, to see if the key year has been set already.
   $aPosts[$iYear][$sMonth]][] = $aRow;
}
```

Comment: i had looked the database. the article's created time is like this 1305357473

Comment: there are no MONTH, year, in the database.

Comment: how many fields i should read out from my database? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your blog postings are in one table (blog?), create an archive table (blog_BAK?) with the exact same structure and create a backup by using the syntax:

```
SELECT INTO
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Thereafter, each time a blog is added/altered insert data into both tables, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your data model? Add a new field to the DB called "archived" and set the default to int(0) if you want it marked as an archive set it to 1.  that way there you still have everything in one place and you just need to read the flag to determine if it is an archive or not. Here is an example of the DB.

```
blog_id | date | title | article | archived
1       | DATE | TITLE | ARTICLE | 1         <- this is archived
2       | DATE | TITLE | ARTICLE | 0         <- this is not
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

**TEST full Example of build a blog style archives**

**CSS File**

```
#Decor 
{
    width:200px;
}

#Decor, #Decor ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.handle { 
    background: transparent url( /images/tree-handle.png ) no-repeat left top; 
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    width:10px; 
    height:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.closed { background-position: left top; }
.opened { background-position: left -10px; }
```

**PHP File**

**just add css code to php html file**

```
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //start the tree in an autocollapsed state
            $('#Decor ul').hide(400);

            $('#Decor li').on('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation(); // prevent links from toggling the nodes
                $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
            });

            // This code opens all hyperlinks in a new window 
            // and avoids anchors
            $('#Decor a').not('[href="#"]').attr('target', '_blank');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<?php
define("DB_USER","");
define("DB_PASS","");
define("DB_HOST","");
define("DB_NAME","");

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_errno());
$s="SELECT *,content_id,COUNT(content_id) AS itemCount FROM content_mast GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_upload,'%Y') DESC";
$sql_result=mysqli_query($link,$s);
?>
<ul id="Decor">
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result))
    {
    $datetime=strtotime($row['date_upload']);
    $tday = date("Y", $datetime);
    $count = $row['itemCount'];
    ?>
     <li class="level1"><?php echo "<u><strong>{$tday} ({$count})</strong></u><br>"; ?>
    <?php
        $s1="select * from content_mast where DATE_FORMAT(date_upload,'%Y')=$tday";
        $q=mysqli_query($link,$s1);
        while($month=mysqli_fetch_row($q))
        {
        ?>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="test.php?date=<?php echo $month[5]; ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime($month[5])); ?></a></li>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
    echo "<br>";
    }
?>
</ul>
</html>
```